# Colours in bar chart form values in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a DataFrame which I'd like to plot using a bar chart. One of the values in the DataFrame should determine the color of the specific bar.

My data looks something like this:

```
data = {"name1":(0, int), "name2":(1, int), "name3":(1, int)}
```

The x-axis should plot all the keys, the y-axis should plot every int.
The 0s and 1s in the tuples should determine the color of the bar they represent.

My current code just plots the DataFrame like it is:

```
df.plot.bar()
```

and gives me the following output:
all values are plotted, except that all bars are only one color
[image]

So my question is, how do I tell pandas to read the 0s and 1s as bar colors?

Comment: Can you post the sample data with values?

Answer (score 0):

You should first transpose your data so it looks like this, then graph it using matplotlib.pyplot.

```
name ,  color,   value
name1,    0  ,    int 
name2,    1  ,    int 
name3,    0  ,    int
```

Here is the code:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data).T 
df_new.columns = ['name', 'color', 'value'] 
df_new.loc[df.color == 0 , 'color'] = 'red' 
df_new.loc[df.color == 1 , 'color'] = 'blue'

fig = plt.figure()
ax.bar(df_new['name'] ,df_new['value'])

for i in df_new.index.values(): 
    ax[i].set_color(df_new.color.loc[i]) 
plt.show()
```